# Thread buffer iterator for preloading files in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have millions of small files and I want to create a `FileLoader` class that use a background thread to pre-load them into a `file pool` in memory in order to speed up things.

My current solution is **not** with a thread buffer:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

class FileLoader(list):
    def __init__(self,file_list):
        # a list of file paths
        self.fl = file_list 

    def Next(self,size=None): # get Next size=N file
        if size: # batch mode
            current_batch = []
            for f in self.fl:
                current_batch.append(open(f).read())
                if len(current_batch) == size:
                    yield current_batch
                    current_batch = []
            if current_batch:
                yield current_batch

        else: # sequence mode
            for f in self.fl:
                yield open(f).read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fl = FileLoader(file_list)
    for fs in fl.Next(5): # the files should be pooled in memory in advance
        # ... my work....
```

Comment: Please edit the Q to specify how you're using this, what you expect, what problem are you encountering.  Offhand I just see a simple typo where you're saying `== n` and probably mean `== size`, but I'm sure there's plenty more beyond the typo!-)

Comment: threads won't make your disk to spin any faster. Are your sure that reading files in parallel actually improves the time performance?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The main computation task will be done on anther cpu/gpu, whenever I consumed some files from the pool, a thread will preload other files to the pool. I think this can speed things up, since for those units all the data are came from the memory without waiting for I/O.

Comment: Reading multiple files in parallel can be faster as the kernel can coalesce multiple adjacent IO requests into one larger request. Of course, the actual benefit can only be determined by profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import multiprocessing

def get_contents(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) # or more
for fs in pool.imap(get_contents, file_list, 5) # 5 is the chunk size here
    # ... your work ...
```

If you don't care about order, you may be faster by using `imap_unordered`. Experiment with the chunk size and the number of processes. Unlike your draft, this method yields contents one at a time, but batching can be wrapped around it.

Comment: How to restrict the memory usage in this methods? I test it and it'll load all the files into memory continuously.

Comment: You'll likely have to write your own implementation of `imap` using `multiprocessing.Queue` which can be given a `maxsize` and made to block if the queue becomes too large.